# PC communication to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pi-3, serial, bluetooth, communication

I am currently trying to setup a serial connection between my computer (windows 10) and my Raspberry Pi 3 via the Bluetooth connection.

On windows I have managed to attribute COM4 to the Raspberry Bluetooth connection.

On the Raspberry Rfcomm0 is setup and I use '/dev/ttyAMA0' as port Id detected

For the code I use:

On Windows:

```
    import time
    import glob
    import serial
    import sys

    def serial_ports():
        """ Lists serial port names

            :raises EnvironmentError:
                On unsupported or unknown platforms
            :returns:
                A list of the serial ports available on the system
        """
        if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
        elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or         sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
            # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
            ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
        elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
            ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
        else:
            raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

        result = []
        for port in ports:
            try:
                s = serial.Serial(port)
                s.close()
                result.append(port)
            except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
                pass
        return result 



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(serial_ports())






    ser = serial.Serial(             
           port=serial_ports()[0],
           baudrate = 9600,
           parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
           stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
           bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
           timeout=1,
           writeTimeout=0
    )
    counter=0


    str(4)

    while counter<20:
           print'Write counter: %d \n'%(counter)
           ser.flush()
           ser.write(str(4))
           ser.write(b's')
           ser.write(('Write counter: %d \n'%(counter))) #('Write         counter: %d \n'%(counter))
           time.sleep(1)
           counter += 1

    ser.close()
```

On the Raspberry Pi 3 I have:

```
    import time
    import serial


    #  '/dev/tty1'
    #  '/dev/ttyAMAO'
    #  '/dev/rfcomm1'
    ser = serial.Serial(              
            port='/dev/ttyAMAO',
            baudrate = 9600,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            timeout=1,
           writeTimeout=0
    )
    counter=0


    while 1:
            x=ser.readline()
            print x
```

Others information:

- The Bluetooth connection is ON
- The Windows Python Have the hand over the COM port
- The RPi3 Python have the hand over the com port

The problem is:
    My windows Python send letters that my Pi Python doesn't see...

(in other word no echo)

Answer (score 2):

[Bluetooth](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/):-

> Bluetooth support is limited at this stage; you can pair with pretty much anything, but you can only usefully connect to devices which support either the Human Interface Device or Audio Sink services – in other words, mice, keyboards and other UI devices, and speakers and headsets.

Comment: thanks for the Info. If I get it right, I should try to setup a Python HID for the communication with my Pi3.