# Sharing my phone's internet to Raspberry Pi 3 via Bluetooth (Tether)

Tags: raspbian, networking, bluetooth, internet

I want to share my mobile data from my phone to the pi (so when I connect to the pi, it automatically gets internet, so I dont have manually setup a mobile hotspot).

I tried this with some older tutorials I found but if I try to establish a PAN connection it says:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pand
sudo: pand: command not found
```

Is pand depricated? Do I have to use something else to this? Or is there an alternative to use for my scenario?

Comment: No idea, but have you installed pand?  It doesn't sound like a package which would be present by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pand` has been deprecated as it uses an API that isn't supported any more. The new way of doing this is to use the D-Bus API which is documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/network-api.txt

An example of how to use that API is at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-network

There is some more details at:

[Host Web Server on Raspberry PI via Bluetooth PAN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108120/host-web-server-on-raspberry-pi-via-bluetooth-pan/114551#114551)

Comment: im testing it with your links asap, thanks for the answer